# Toggling the image hovering effect on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would need help on toggling the image hovering effect on click of a button. I have a set of images with id 'myImg' Below code is not working. Can someone please help. Thanks.

```js
$("button.hov").click(function() {
  if ($(this).text().trim() == 'Hover ON') {
    $(this).text("Hover OFF");
    $('img#myImg.hover').css({
      "-webkit-transform": 'none'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).text("Hover ON");
    $('img#myImg.hover').css({
      "-webkit-transform": 'scale(3, 3)'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
img#myImg:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(3, 3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button hov" style="margin-left: 2px;height: 30px;">
HOVER ON
</button>

<img id="myImg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg" width="240" height="160"/>
<img id="myImg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" width="240" height="160"/>
```

Comment: First and most important: `I have a set of images with id 'myImg'` HTML elements can NOT have same id, id needs to be unique. Use classes instead. Secund: please show HTML and CSS with relevant markup, you are talking about images and see none in your HTML. make a [mre], use `<>` in editor to make snippet.

Comment: If you're using `<button>` and it's in a `form` then make sure you use `<button type='button' ...` to ensure it doesn't POST your form (`type=submit` is default)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of converting to a snippet and adding some sample images (both with the same `id=` to match the statement "I have a set of images with id")

Comment: Off topic: you also *generally* don't want to give the `text` semantic meaning - ie don't look for the text "Hover On" - if you change it to "Switch on hover" in the future, your js will stop working.   Use a `data-` attribute and `$(this).data("hoveron", true)` (etc) (or some other method of course).  Edit: in fact this is one issue you currently have:  `"Hover ON" !== "HOVER ON"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include hover in your jquery selector, instead, define the hover effect with a class, and make use of [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

**HTML**

```
<button class="button hov" style="margin-left: 2px;height: 30px;">
    HOVER ON
</button>
<img id="myImg" src="/your-image"/>
```

**JS**

```
$("button.hov").click(function () {
    if ($(this).text().trim() == 'Hover ON') {
        $(this).text("Hover OFF");
        $('img#myImg').removeClass("hoverEffect");
    }
    else {
        $(this).text("Hover ON");
        $('img#myImg').addClass("hoverEffect");
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
img#myImg.hoverEffect:hover {
       -webkit-transform: scale(3, 3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. This worked to perfect with minimal changes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you get started

```js
$(".toggle-scale").click(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var buttonText = el.text().trim();
  if (buttonText == 'Hover On') {
    el.text("Hover OFF");
    $('.image').addClass('enlarge');
  } else {
    el.text("Hover On");
    $('.image.enlarge').removeClass('enlarge');
  }
});
```

```css
.image-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out
}

.image.enlarge {
  transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle-scale" style="margin-left: 2px;height: 30px;">Hover On</button>
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" class="image" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `id=` to `class=` in the HTML/CSS and JS, you already have what you need, just swap in/out the css `scale` that you already having by giving it a classname (`hover` in the case below) and toggling that class:

```js
$("button.hov").click(function() {
  $("img.myImg").toggleClass("hover");
  $(this).text(() =>
    $("img.myImg").hasClass("hover") 
      ? "switch hover off" 
      : "switch hover on"
    );
});
```

```css
img.myImg.hover:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(3, 3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="button hov" style="margin-left: 2px;height: 30px;">
  switch hover on
</button>
<hr/>

<img class="myImg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg" width="240" height="160" />
<img class="myImg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" width="240" height="160" />
```